# WPF Textbox failed to trigger lostFocus on first try?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, lostfocus

```
EventManager
    .RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), 
                          TextBox.GotFocusEvent, 
                          new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus));

EventManager
    .RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), 
                          TextBox.LostFocusEvent, 
                          new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_LostFocus));
```

From the code above, I will be able to trigger `TextBox_GotFocus()` method once the textbox is focused and when the focus is lost, `TextBox_LostFocus()` method will be triggered.

Now I have a page that having 2 textbox and a button.

When I first click on textbox 1, `TextBox_GotFocus()` successfully being triggered and when I click on textbox 2, textbox1's `TextBox_LostFocus()` will be triggered and textbox2's `TextBox_GotFocus()` will be triggered, which is as what I expected. But if I try to click on the button, `TextBox_LostFocus()` will failed to trigger on first try?

In conclusion, after `TextBox_GotFocus()` being triggered, when I click on button, why `TextBox_LostFocus()` will not be triggered for the first click? When I click second time, then `TextBox_LostFocus()` will be execute

Comment: I used to your description to setup a test WPF application and the TextBox_LostFocus triggers correctly on the button press. Can you provide a little more information? Do these three controls have the same parent control? (i.e. do you have tabs or something that might complicate the scenario?)

Comment: Please provide sample xaml